# Find the redirect-url for POST request in rest-client

Tags: ruby, rest, rest-client

I need to get the redirect url name for the POST request i am making.

```
begin
  RestClient.post url, :param => p
rescue => e
  e.inspect
end
```

Response: 
`"302 Found: <html><body>You are being <a href=\"https://www.abcd.com/971939frwddm\">redirected</a>.</body></html>\n"`

What i need is just the uri : `www.abcd.com/971939frwddm`

My question is whether i can get the uri directly from object `e` without regexing the string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should [work](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/37815dd3cab3f2d4353a1f721509ce99dbe48651/lib/restclient/exceptions.rb#L161):

```
begin
  RestClient.post url, :param => p
rescue Redirect => e
  redirected_url = e.url
end
```

---

**Update**
Since the above did not work, I suggest you try:

```
RestClient.post(url, :param => p) do |response, request, result, &block|
  if [301, 302, 307].include? response.code
    redirected_url = response.headers[:location]
  else
    response.return!(request, result, &block)
  end
end
```

(this is a combination of the suggested implementation of how to [follow redirection on all request types](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#result-handling) and `Request`'s implementation of [`follow_redirection`](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/f36246ae2c3463ca4ebdd70dccf45b112a3ffe0f/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb#L64)

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'url' for #<RestClient::Found:0xa534d64>` comes for `e.url`

Comment: Thank you for this,  you can catch `RestClient::Exception => ex` and via `ex.response.headers[:location]` get redirect url.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone runs into something similar and wants to get the final url after the redirect, the following worked for me.

```
result = RestClient.get(url, :user_agent => AGENT, :cookies => @cookies){ |response, request, result, &block|
  if [301, 302, 307].include? response.code
    response.follow_redirection(request, result, &block)
  else
    final_url = request.url
    response.return!(request, result, &block)
  end
}
```

final_url will contain the final redirect_url

Comment: `final_url` needs to initialized beforehand, otherwise it's only accessible in the blog and not outside. A simple `final_url = nil` works. Tested in Ruby 2.1.3.